# Arduino Libaries folder

Tags: arduino, library, mac, osx

Where do i put the Arduino "Library" folder on a Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Libraries should go to *~/Documents/Arduino/libraries/* folder. This way when you upgrade Arduino IDE it wont overwrite your libraries. If Arduino IDE does not show your recently added library you need to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a folder called 'Library' for my own version (0017).

If you mean the preferences.txt that goes in *"/Users/(username)/Library/Arduino"*.

Otherwise all libraries are inside the package (right click on the Arduino icon to access) then contained in *"/Contents/Resources/Java"* there are 'lib' and 'libaries' folders.

Hope that helps a little :)